# My Computer crashes every time after I run this - Abort Dynamic Evaluation error

Tags: evaluation, dynamic, crash

This code makes my computer crash, every time I run it.

```
Manipulate[
    g[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 - x, 1 <= x}, {x, x < 1}}];
    Solve[g[x] == g[m x], x],
    {{m, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 0.1}
]
```

What's wrong with this? After a time, I receive this error message: [image]

I use *Mathematica 12.0*

If I click `Continue Waiting`, it will end up crashing.

Comment: When you say your "Computer" crashes do you really mean that?  As in the OS crashes and you have to reboot?

Comment: @Michael  cpu and memory is so demanding, it cost almost all resources. Finally OS crashes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's causing the problem, but you generally want to avoid re-defining functions inside of dynamics like these. Every time the manipulate re-calculates the result, it redefines `g` and this seems to cause some sort of infinite update loop. It's better to do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Solve[g[x] == g[m x], x],
 {{m, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 0.1},
 Initialization :> (
   g[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 - x, 1 <= x}, {x, x < 1}}]
   )
 ]
```

**edit**

It seems like the problem persists for the OP, so here's 2 more suggestions. First of all, try using the `TrackedSymbols` option:

```
Manipulate[
 Solve[g[x] == g[m x], x],
 {{m, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 0.1}, 
 Initialization :> (g[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 - x, 1 <= x}, {x, x < 1}}]),
 TrackedSymbols :> {m}
]
```

Failing that, another good trick it to encapsulate the output in `Dynamic` with a `TrackedSymbols` option:

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic[
  Solve[g[x] == g[m x], x],
  TrackedSymbols :> {m}
 ],
 {{m, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 0.1}, 
 Initialization :> (g[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 - x, 1 <= x}, {x, x < 1}}])
]
```

If that doesn't work, I suspect there might be a hardware issue or a problem with your Mathematica installation.

Comment: The message still keeps popping up even I used yours instead

Comment: Hmmm, strange. What version are you using? I'll add another suggestion to the answer.

Comment: But it works like a charm after I reset steps `du` from 0.1 to 1/10. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: "But it works like a charm after I reset steps du from 0.1 to 1/10." That honestly makes no sense to me. If anything, I'd expect the reverse to work. Oh well...

Comment: Everything works great after you edit your answer.