# Abort dynamics error

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I am encountering a problem when I use the function Manipulate. Even when I run the simple code

```
f[a_,x_]:=a*x
Manipulate[Plot[f[a,x],{x,-1,1}],{a,1,2}]
```

I obtain

[image]

I have tried to reset the Kernel, restart the computer, and also increase the time for returning this error message to 90s -- Anything does not work.
Any thoughts?

**Importante note:** I should say that if I go to the examples of Mathematica in the Documentation Center, the Manipulate works

[image]

Comment: Unable to reproduce on "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)"

Comment: Do you have other dynamic outputs in your open notebook(s)?

Comment: No, not at all. I am literally just creating a new Mathematica file and typing the ordinary commands above.

Comment: Runs fine on MMA 12.3 Windows

Comment: @denis Most probably, there are problems with Java on your PC .

Comment: Have you tried this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162696/how-to-avoid-abort-dynamic-evaluation-error

Comment: @Syed Yes I did. It did not work.

Comment: @Rom38 the weird part is that within the documentation of Mathematica the manipulate does work fine. I think that if is indeed a issue with Java, that would also not work, no!?

Comment: Try this if you haven't already: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216029/my-computer-crashes-every-time-after-i-run-this-abort-dynamic-evaluation-error

Comment: Copy paste the documentation example in a  new notebook (fresh start) and see if that works.

Comment: @sined, The dynamic content that is stored in MMA Help is already created on the properly working PC. Your PC just play it. But the new dynamic objects that you made right now feel all the bugs of your installation of Java and MMA.